# left adjointable functors

Tags: category-theory, terminology

When a functor $F$ is left adjoint to some functor $G$, then one usually says that "$F$ is a left adjoint". Is this grammatically correct? Wouldn't it be more accurate to say that "$F$ is right adjoint**able**"? Similarly, one already speaks of (left or right) "dualizable objects" in a monoidal category. Notice that both notions, adjointness and duality, can be unified via $2$-categories. Googling yields "left adjointable" only in the context of operator algebras.

In German, the phrase "$F$ is ein Linksadjungierter" looks even more awkward to me; "$F$ ist rechtsadjungierbar" is much better.

Other suggestions are also welcome.

Comment: For me, "$F$ is left adjointable" sounds more like "$F$ has a left adjoint", which is the opposite of "$F$ is a left adjoint".

Comment: Dualization and (Cat) adjointness can be viewed as both a process (eg. dualize a vector space/"reverse" a forgetful functor) and a property (eg. an object is dualizable/a functor is left adjoint). For various reasons I think we prefer the first aspect of dualization and the second aspect of adjointness.
The lack of a verb meaning "to turn into the second member of the adjoint pair" analogous to "dualize" doesn't help (German I presume can use ?adjungieren here).

Comment: @ZhenLin: That's true :( ... so other suggestions are welcome (please *as answers*).

Comment: Doesn't *$f$ is left invertible* mean that it has a left inverse, as opposed to being a left inverse? So I would interpret *being left adjointable* as having a left adjoint.

Comment: @StefanHamcke: Yes, this is also what Zhen Lin pointed out. I have now edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle, "$F$ is a left adjoint" is fine because the adjunction is determined uniquely up to unique isomorphism by $F$. This seems to contradict your intuition that "$F$ is a left adjoint" sounds wrong, but it's perfectly consistent with standard usage such as talking about "the" limit of $G$: this sort of usage works fine except in contexts where it's important to distinguish between uniquely isomorphic objects. In such contexts, we can say things like "a limit of $G$", or "$F$ is a functor which admits a right adjoint". It's okay that these expressions are awkward because context doesn't often demand that we resort to them. In principle, we could do everything in Homotopy Type Theory, where uniquely isomorphic things are literally equal, and these strange contexts couldn't even come up.

So the real question is why we say "dualizable", even in contexts where we don't need to distinguish between uniquely isomorphic things. I suspect it's because often in a context where it makes sense to ask whether an object is dualizable, there are actually two notions at duality at play, one in the adjoint sense and one in another sense. For example, in vector spaces, there's a non-adjoint sense of "dual" given by $\mathrm{Hom}(-,k)$. We say "dualizable" to force the interpretation of the word into the adjoint sense. This just happens to work because in the non-adjoint sense, every vector space $V$ has a "dual" $\mathrm{Hom}(V,k)$ so it wouldn't make sense to ask whether it's "dualizable".

Comment: My problem is not about uniqueness! It's about the term "F is a left adjoint." which immediately leads to the question "of what"? Of course, one defines "left adjoint := left adjoint to something", but is this *grammatically* correct? Aren't there, in any language, relations which cannot refer to single objects?

Comment: Your objection is invalid. For example, "He is a father" is perfectly grammatical as a sentence.

Comment: @ZhenLin: That's true. So you say that "is a left adjoint." is grammatically correct. Why not as an answer? I would like to accept correct answers ...

Comment: Well, there is also "It is a left half", which sounds less grammatical than "It is _the_ left half". My point is that the grammaticality of "$F$ is a left adjoint" cannot be determined by general arguments.

Comment: @ZhenLin: You actually just gave a general argument for the grammaticallity of that sentence: it's identical in structure to unquestionably grammatical sentences such as "he is a good father". Furthermore, it's not even semantically anomalous in any way (unlike for example syntactically also valid but meaningless "he is a left father").

Comment: As for the "It is a left half", I think the problem with that is the unrealistic situation the sentence describes (you know something's a left half of something, but you don't know or care of what).
In contrast, saying that a functor is a left adjoint is very meaningful even if you don't know what the right adjoint is.

Comment: For me, even "is an adjoint." sounds problematic (at least, in German, "ist ein Adjungierter."), because I am not sure if the **relation** "X adjoint to Y" can be "nominalized".